# Memory leak in python on Ubuntu vs Windows

Tags: python, windows, ubuntu, memory, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to run a computationally intense python program with a large memory footprint (~300Mb), and am limited by my local machine, 4-core i5 Intel w/ 4GB RAM running Windows 7 64-bit. 
I decided to manually multiprocess, MIMD-style, by running 3 python processes on 3 partitions of the dataset, since python would only use 25% of my cpu for a single console. These processes have been running, slowly, at 25% cpu each and ~300Mb memory. However, I'm limited to using this one machine for all work processes, and wanted to utilize AWS EC2 to offload the computation.

I spun up 3 Ubuntu 14.4 EC2 instances with 1 virtual CPU and 1GB RAM each, copied the exact data sets and code and attempted to run (backgrounded via screen and sudo nohup python program.py &) the three identical programs, one on each VM.

However, the memory usage on the ubuntu instances is much, much higher, reaching 100% usage and causing a memory error.

**What is causing this discrepancy in memory usage between Ubuntu and Windows, and what can I do to fix it, assuming I have optimized my program (i.e. avoiding intrusive code restructuring)?**

I've looked in to memory limits on unix, but I believe that will only cause my program to reach a memory error sooner.

Below is a sample output from dmesg after the termination of my backgrounded python process.

```
[ 1326.630939] python[1200]: segfault at 24 ip 0000000000537632 sp 00007fff55111400       error 6 in python2.7[400000+2bd000]
```

I am running Standard Python 2.7.6 on both machines, and utilizing only standard modules with the exception of numpy. 
I saw this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141546/python-memoryerror-issue-on-ubuntu-but-not-on-windows-when-running-matpplotlibs) and have checked my 64-bit -ness on both python and ubuntu.

Each Ubuntu EC2 machine is running only one process:

```
$ screen
$ sudo nohup python program.py &
```

`top` shows python.exe running smoothly at 99% cpu and starting at a low %memory, but the memory% slowly grows.

My local Windows machine I opened up 3 shells and executed in each

```
$ python program.py
```

TaskManager shows flat, consistent memory usage for all 3 python processes.

Comment: Updated. The program itself is not multithreaded, though I experimented with threading module. Runtime per entry was increased by an order of magnitude with multithreading. @ScottLawson

Comment: I've got a similar segfault [  417.876501] python[4295]: segfault at 24 ip 0000000000517b4c sp 00007fff24d8b360 error 6 in python[400000+2bd000]

it occurs only of digitalocean instances, could not reproduce it locally. Tried OSX and Ubuntu.

Comment: Same error here, when on an EC2 Ubuntu instance running a large MongoDB job.  Can't find any fixes.